# FontAwesome icon not showing at all on chromium-based browsers

Tags: css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I'm trying to update some theme from fontawesome 4 to 5. So far everything seems to work fine, the icons in `i` tags are displayed. Except for one specific icon that displays as a css pseudo-element.

I followed what the FA docs said but the icon still doesn't appear. Not even as a square, just as a plain nothing.

Here's the codes used. It's supposed to display an icon in the middle of the `hr` :

html head:

```
<link href="css/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

html body:

```
<hr class="star-light">
```

css:

```
hr.star-light:after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f005";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -.8em;
    padding: 0 .25em;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

I also tried to put the conflict detection script and it actually found one... But it doesn't make sense since there's only one conflict: the fa's css itself `all.min.css`... And i'm not even sure it's linked to the problem... It's been 2 hours i'm stuck there and my searches didn't give me anything relevant. Anyone have an idea of what's going on? Or things i can try?

Here's the whole repository, in case you want to try. it's a hugo theme. My repo already includes fontawesome 5:
https://github.com/maxlefou/hugo-freelancer-theme

**EDIT:** I just found the issue. It's just silly: the problem only occurs on chrome and chromium browsers. Everything works on Firefox. Go figures...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your code is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/hu0nz9t3/

Comment: i know right? everywhere else i tested it worked, but to me, it doesn't...

I'm gonna include the whole repo with the code https://github.com/maxlefou/hugo-freelancer-theme

Comment: May do you have ad blocker enabled?

Comment: Actually I just noticed the problem occurs on chromium-based browsers. the icon appears on Firefox. :|

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; to font-family: "FontAwesome";

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Didn't worked. In fact, I was expecting all the icons to stop working with your idea but actually nothing changed. Except for the hr icon, all of them worked.
The problem seems to be coming from chromium-based browsers anyway

Comment: Can you share the URL of the page?

Comment: It's a hugo theme. the repository is here https://github.com/maxlefou/hugo-freelancer-theme